# Excel VBA Custom sort not working properly

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Ok, So i'm trying to do a custom sort on my Classified Table via a Reference Table, here is a small portion of the reference table

[image: Reference Table]

Now, whenever I sort my Classified Table, it becomes this

[image: Classified Table]

as you can see, It only sorts up to a certain number of rows (C&J Global Enterprises), then the rest is sorted alphabetically (Which is not what I want)

Here is my VBA Code

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Activate()

Dim MainSheet As Worksheet, RefSheet As Worksheet
Set MainSheet = Worksheets("Classifieds Client Table")
Set RefSheet = Worksheets("RefTable")

Dim RangeOne As Range, RangeTwo As Range
Set RangeOne = MainSheet.Range("A2:A150")
Set RangeTwo = RefSheet.Range("A1:A137")

Dim MainRange As Range
Set MainRange = MainSheet.Range("A2:H150")

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=RangeTwo
MainSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear

MainRange.Sort Key1:=MainRange, Header:=xlNo, _
OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100944/code-an-excel-vba-sort-with-a-custom-order-and-a-value-containing-commas

Comment: If C&J Global Enterprises are indeed listed in RangeTwo try removing the ampersand - just a guess, based on the conclusion that if the code is not at fault the data must be.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if your sample code didn't include parts unrelated to the question. (See [mcve].)

Comment: @ashleedawg, sorry, thought it would help -- to Variatus, I will try it now -- to TimWilliams will check it

Comment: Nope, we're just interested in the broken parts (and related data, of course!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SortOn` is not a valid parameter for *`Range.Sort`*.

I suspect you meant to use **`SortMethod`**.

Fix that (and also remove any extraneous code that's unrelated to the answer) and if it's still not sorting by your custom list I will try to edit my answer and figure it out.

### More Information:

- MSDN : [`Range.Sort` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel)

Comment: Sir, I have edited my code but it still doesn't sort properly. I have removed all special characters, replaced numbers with words but it still doesn't sort correctly. It only sorts correctly up to a certain row and then the rest is sorted alphabetically

Comment: okay, I can take a look... but can you replace the 1st screenshot with the same data but pasted in text (as a code block) so I can copy & paste it?

Comment: Why do you use a `+1` when referring to the list?

Comment: Actually, I used the answer in the link provided by Tim Williams, you can take a look at the file I use
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_O4RToVeFjmELIkNGX17ud9HL3al1FhE

Comment: yeah I'm looking

Comment: Dude.   The  [updated] code from your question, run against the data from your link, works perfectly.  Did you try running it since you shortened the code?

Comment: the copy on your OneDrive didn't have VBA so I pasted in your code from the question, and it sorts the entire list exactly list it's supposed to.  Here is the file back:  http://jmp.sh/PU0Sz5s

Comment: What the. When I try my code, I get
Method 'AddCustomList' of object '_Application' failed
and when I debug it, it points to this line
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=RangeTwo

Comment: Sir, can you try this complete code of mine?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aHE5laLOdfKESDcQ7TGX1HBSirOG0HBW
I think there is something wrong with it

Comment: Did you try the one I sent back?  I don't have time to do it again, sorry. Also add `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, the file you provided doesn't have any VBA Code

Comment: don't use the online view; download the file. or, just copy the code from your verson in to the blank module and run it

Comment: Sir, The code that I posted is still not working. I already tried different ways, but it still only sorts up to a certain row, then the rest (rows below) sorts alphabetically and does not follow my reference table