# Extract name of lowest values excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

I have the following table:

[image: name-value-table]

I would like to extract using formulas or vba (if necessary) the name of the rows with less value (4 lowest for example). In this case the answer would be: Name 6, Name 7, Name 8 as they havel value = 0 and Name 4 as it is the first name with value = 1.

This is what I tried:

[image: attemp]

The problem is that the match formula cannot distinguish the correct row of the extracted value as there are varios names with the same value.

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Also please edit the post to include your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: MS Excel version: Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.013127.21962). Own attempt added too.

Answer (score 3):

Right, with Microsoft365 you may try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:B11,2,1),SEQUENCE(4))
```

Comment: Thaks for your help! Is there any alternative for MS Excel 2016? As it is the version I have in my work computer

Comment: Yeah probably but I closed the laptop down for the night. I'm sure someone else will help you out 

Answer (score 2):

The formulas below, since your example implies that you want items with a value less than or equal to the 4th lowest value, will return five (5) values since you have three zero's and two one's. The 4th lowest value is a `1`. If you want to use some other algorithm to limit the return to just four values, please be more specific.

With O365

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$11,($B$2:$B$11<=SMALL($B$2:$B$11,4)))
```

With XL2016

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$2:$B$11<=SMALL($B$2:$B$11,4))*ROW($B$2:$B$11),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(B2:B11,"<="&SMALL(B2:B11,4)))))-1)
```

*The `-1` at the end is to compensate for indexing into an array starting at row 2 rather than row 1. Adjust for whatever row your data starts in*

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way but this is what I came up with.

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MOD(SMALL($B$2:$B$11+ROW($B$2:$B$11)/1000000,ROWS($D$2:D2)),1)*1000000-ROW($B$1))`

You will probably need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it an array formula.  I don't have Excel 2016 to test with.

Answer (score 1):

So, for S&G I had a play with VBA. I decided I would do the ascending sort on the `Value` column first, then set desired target area value to the first N rows of `Name` column.

I restored the original order of `Name` column by storing it as a temporary custom order early on, and sorting with it at end. I checked custom order syntax against [Steve Mallory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104297)'s answer.

```
Option Explicit
Const N As Long = 4

Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B11")
    SortAndTopN rng
End Sub

Public Sub SortAndTopN(ByVal rng As Range)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=.Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value
        With .Parent.AutoFilter.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Columns(2), SortOn:=0, Order:=1, DataOption:=0
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
            rng.Offset(0, rng.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(N, 1).Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Columns(1), SortOn:=0, Order:=1, CustomOrder:=Application.CustomListCount, DataOption:=0
            .Apply
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
End Sub
```

---