# Assign variable for CustomOrder parameter in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x
    x = "ow, bv, xz"
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), CustomOrder:=x
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), Order:=xlDescending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to use CustomOrder and assign a variable x to the string. When using the string directly, it works well but not with using variable
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Perhaps remove the space in the string?  `"ow,bv,xz"`

Comment: @PeterT ... already tried, still throws a Type Mismatch.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104297/4717755) suggests using an array to specify your sort order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug. The following work for me:

```
CustomOrder:=Cstr(x)
```

```
CustomOrder:=Join(Split(x)) 'overkill, but for laughs
```

```
CustomOrder:=x & vbNullString
```